# Trying to fillet an edge that is result of a boolean. Any suggestions?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a model that is a result of a series of booleans. On this model, one resulting edge looks like this:

[image]

I need to fillet this to make it rounded. Any quick ideas ?

I tried using the Bevel tool (Ctrl-b) and meshmachine plugin but it turns out like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Quite possibly there may not be a quick fix, but have you removed doubles before using the bevel tool?

Comment: There aren't any double edges or anything . The shape becomes like this because some edges are  very close to the bevel while others are pretty far away .